# Issue with IIS and error in biztalk server

Tags: iis, service, internet, 500-error, biztalk

I have created an application within BizTalk. It includes a receive location configured with TYPE: HTTP, with a BizTalkServerIsolatedHost handler. The URI created looks like this: /ph_qa/BTSHTTPReceive.dll. It also has a receive pipeline of AS2Receive and a send pipeline of AS2Send. We are experiencing issues with communication with the client as they encounter a 500 error with the message "Remote server returned response code 500 and error message Internal Server Error".

We have set up a new application pool in IIS, which shares the physical path with another service already mounted within IIS that is working fine. The path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server\HttpReceive.

From our side, when the client sends a message, we see the following error:
"The BizTalk HTTP receive adapter failed to initialize itself. Possible reasons:

Receive location URL is not created/configured correctly.
Receive location is not enabled.
HTTP receive adapter is not running under a user that has access to management and message databases.
Isolated host instance is not created for HTTP Receive adapter."

And another error message says:

"The Messaging Engine failed to register an adapter 'HTTP'. Details: 'Registering multiple adapter types within the same process is not a supported configuration. For example, HTTP and SOAP receive adapters cannot co-exist in the same process'."

From what I understand, the problem seems to originate from the service created. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, as we have been facing this issue for weeks.

Regards.